# PHP parse error (unexpected token) when using match() function

Tags: php

I have moved my website over to a new server and i am trying to get one of my websites up and running but i get a log error as follows

> "'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token ",""

in the file i have

```
// Given a string such as "comment_123" or "id_57", it returns the final, numeric id.
function split_id($str)
{
    return match('/[_-]([0-9]+)$/', $str, 1);
}
```

how could i fix this ?

Comment: [match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) is a new control structure from PHP 8 and forward. You can no longer use it as a function name.

Comment: do you know how to change this to be working for php 8 ?

Comment: Change the name of that function to not use a keyword

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `function match()` should now be `function my_match()` or whatever works best for your naming